# Clip long video segment quickly

Tags: ffmpeg

Let's say I have a video called Concert.mp4.  I want to extract a performance from it quickly with minimal reencoding.  I want to do the equivalent of this, but faster:

```
ffmpeg -i "Concert.mp4" -ss 00:11:45 -to 00:18:15  -preset veryfast -y artist.mp4
```

This takes 17 seconds, which is way too long for our needs.

Now, it turns out that 11:45 and 18:15 don't fall on iframes, so if you try this you will get a 3 second delay at the beginning before the video shows:

```
ffmpeg -i "Concert.mp4" -ss 00:11:45 -to 00:18:15 -c copy -y artist.mp4
```

Running this command, we can see where we need to cut:

```
ffprobe -read_intervals "11:00%19:00" -v error -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -select_streams v -of csv=p=0 "Concert.mp4" > frames.txt
```

So what we need to do is encode the first 3.708 seconds, copy the middle, and then encode the last 5.912 seconds.

I can get the 3 segments to all look perfect (by themselves) like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 698.698 -i "Concert.mp4" -ss 6.302 -t 3.708 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -c:s copy -y clipbegin.mp4

ffmpeg -ss 708.708 -to 1089.088 -i "Concert.mp4" -c copy -y clipmiddle.mp4

ffmpeg -ss 1089.088 -i "Concert.mp4" -t 5.912 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -c:s copy -y clipend.mp4

ffmpeg -f concat -i segments.txt -c copy -y artist.mp4
```

segments.txt of course contains the following:

```
file 'clipbegin.mkv'
file 'clipmiddle.mkv'
file 'clipend.mkv'
```

I saw this solution presented here, but no amount of tweaking gets it to work for me:

https://superuser.com/a/1039134/73272

As far as I can tell, this method doesn't work at all.  It crashes VLC pretty hard no matter what I try.

The combined video keeps glitching after the 3 seconds, probably because the PTS times are different or something (using some options, I have seen warning messages to this effect).  Is there anything I can add to the commands above to get this to work?  The only requirement is that the middle command must not re-encode the video, but must do a fast copy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The re-encodes must match or exceed the codec properties of the copied portion. For H264, profile, level, no. of reference frames, at a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the answer was just that the latest VLC seems to be buggy.  What I did above plays just fine with a very slight pause at the cut point in `ffplay`, `mplayer` and `PotPlayer`.

Following @Gyan's advice, I set the profile and level to match the original (using `-profile:v main -level:v 4`) and even the slight pause went away.

```
ffmpeg -ss 698.698 -i "Concert.mp4" -ss 6.302 -t 3.708 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -c:s copy -profile:v main -level:v 4 -y clipbegin.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 708.708 -to 1089.088 -i "Concert.mp4" -c copy -y clipmiddle.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 1089.088 -i "Concert.mp4" -t 5.912 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -c:s copy -profile:v main -level:v 4 -y clipend.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -i segments.txt -c copy -y artist.mp4
```